# Failed to convert parameter value from a String to a Int32 while passing integer variable

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, ado.net

I have a stored procedure like this:

```
 ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[T_TransactionSummary]  
                            @startDate datetime,  
                            @endDate datetime,       
                            @locations integer    
    AS
    BEGIN 

.................
................
WHERE (Transaction_tbl.dtime BETWEEN @fromDate AND @toDate)
AND (Location_tbl.Locid IN (@locations))
```

I've got a ListBox which populates the @locations parameter (an integer), and two DateTimePicker controls for the `@fromDate` and `@toDate.`
I took my listbox value like this:

```
cnt = LSTlocations.SelectedItems.Count
 Dim list As New List(Of Integer)
        Dim locid As Integer
        If cnt > 0 Then
            For i = 0 To cnt - 1
                Dim locationanme As String = LSTlocations.SelectedItems(i).ToString
                locid = RecordID("Locid", "Location_tbl", "LocName", locationanme)
                list.Add(locid)
            Next
End If
 Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter
        Dim ds As New DataSet
        Dim cmd23 As New SqlCommand("T_TransactionSummary", con.connect)
        cmd23.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        cmd23.Parameters.Add("@startDate", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50, ParameterDirection.Input).Value = startdate
        cmd23.Parameters.Add("@endDate", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50, ParameterDirection.Input).Value = enddate
        cmd23.Parameters.Add("@locations", SqlDbType.Int).Value = String.Join(",", list)
 da.SelectCommand = cmd23
        da.Fill(ds)
```

if the code reach here i am getting error like this:

> "Failed to convert parameter value from a String to a Int32

i know am getting  error in this line

```
cmd23.Parameters.Add("@locations", SqlDbType.Int).Value = String.Join(",", list)
```

i want go the parameter to stored procedure like 1,2,3 only
  i am using vb.net. what is wrong with my code..any help is great appreciate ..

Comment: of course a kind of string like `"0,1,2,3"` cannot be parsed as a number.

Comment: so what i have to change ???

Comment: For SQL2008+ I would use [TVP](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2112/table-value-parameters-in-sql-server-2008-and-net-c/)

Answer (score 1):

If you define your stored procedure parameters are `DATETIME` (good thing!):

```
@startDate datetime,
```

then you must also define them as such in your VB.NET code!!

This is **wrong**:

```
cmd23.Parameters.Add("@startDate", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50, ParameterDirection.Input).Value = startdate
```

It should be:

```
cmd23.Parameters.Add("@startDate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value =  ........
```

Comment: sir my error in cmd23.Parameters.Add("@locations", SqlDbType.Int).Value = String.Join(",", list) only..string like "0,1,2,3" cannot be parsed as a number.so what change i have to make?

Answer (score 1):

At this line:

```
cmd23.Parameters.Add("@locations", SqlDbType.Int).Value = String.Join(",", list)
```

You are producing a string like `1,2,3,4,5`

Then you need to delete the delimitter when joining the list:

```
String.Join("", list)
```

That will produce a serie of numbers like `12345`

Comment: sir..i want go the parameter to stored procedure like 1,2,3 only

Comment: Sorry I don't understanded much well (my English is not very good). If you want the vlaue to be `1,2,3` then change the value type of the stored procedure from `Integer` to `String`, you are attempting to set a string value not a numeric value.

Comment: u mean change integer parameter to nvarchar??

Comment: my locid is integer.so locations parameter should take integer varibale?

Comment: `@locations integer` and `"@locations", SqlDbType.Int` change it should take a string variable since you are not attempting to set a integer value

Comment: sir,i given like this only.."@locations", SqlDbType.Int in code and @locations integer in stored procedure

Comment: insted of this what o have to change? u said change to string..how i can do that?

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server does not currently support the functionality as you describe (although I wish it did, I have this same problem.)  If you have the ability to create objects on SQL server, you can create what is called a Table-Valued Parameters AKA parameters in the shape of a table.

Basically you create a "table type" on the server. It is an empty table that describes the shape of data table that you can pass to a parameter. In your case you would create a table with one column.

Let's walk through this example. Create your table type object on SQL server:

```
CREATE TYPE dbo.CategoryTableType AS TABLE
( CategoryID int, CategoryName nvarchar(50) )
```

Now in your stored procedures, or dynamic SQL in your code, you can declare table-valued parameters based on that type. This creates a stored procedure with one input parameter of type dbo.CategoryTableType. Now you can pass in a rows with columns CategoryID and CategoryName. Notice it must be read only.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_UpdateCategories 
(@tvpNewCategories dbo.CategoryTableType READONLY)
```

Now you can pass values to your parameterized SQL statement. Notice your SQL Parameter must be of type SqlDBType.Structured.:

```
Dim sqlParameter As New SqlClient.SqlParameter
sqlParameter.ParameterName = "@tvpNewCategories"
sqlParameter.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int
sqlParameter.Value = addedCategories
sqlParameter.TypeName = "dbo.CategoryTableType"
```

You create your input data as a VB or C# DataTable:

```
'Create a DataTable with the modified rows.
Dim addedCategories As DataTable = _
CategoriesDataTable.GetChanges(DataRowState.Added)
```

More info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675163(v=vs.110).aspx

Side note: the simplest, but least elegant, way to do this is to have dynamic SQL in your code and do a string.replace and replace @tvpNewCategories with (1, 2, 3, 4)